# Display textView label and make it clickable with dynamic URL

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

I have a `textView` which should always have the same `text` : "Link öffnen". This is what I got so far:

```
let linkLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.textAlignment = .left
        v.isSelectable = false
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        let padding = v.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
        v.textContainerInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -padding, bottom: 0, right: -padding)
        v.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Link öffnen", attributes:
            [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 15)!,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkCustom])
        
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
}()
```

It displays the `textView` exactly how I want it to. What is missing now is the `clickable` function. This `textView`  is inside a `tableViewCell` and it should be clickable and each should open a certain `url` which is saved inside the `cell`. I know I can use `SFSafariViewController` for example for that. The problem is to make the `textView` clickable. What is the easiest/best practice way to do this here?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using NSAttributedString then you can use [link attribute](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1535719-link). Also in Interface Builder you need to turn on selectable property on your TextView.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate on this ?

Comment: You need to add `NSAttributedString.Key.link` attribute to you string and as a value you need to set your link. In case of selectable property you need to select UITextView -> Show the attributes inspector tab -> and on `behavior` option you need to have enabled `Selectable` property. Clicking on the link will be handled by the iOS then.

Comment: You will also need  `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: where can I access the tap? sorry never used that before so could you maybe give an example ?

Comment: Example using Interface Builder or programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

For a really clean way to solve this try out [ActiveLabel](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) Great for links hashtags and mentions within your textView. Also very easy to customise.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I prefer not using a library for this